# Resizing image to circular size in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, frontend, tailwind-css

[image]

Currently, my image is getting shown like this, but I want them to be circular and each of equal width and height.

They aren't square now and I have added the below CSS tailwind code but still am not getting them all in the circular.

```
<div className="cursor-pointer">
        <div className="w-full overflow-hidden rounded-full mb-2  border border-black">
          <img src={banner} alt={title} loading="lazy" className="w-full" />
        </div>
        <h3 className="text-sm md:text-lg font-medium ">{title}</h3>
      </div>
```

I have tried different iterations with hard-coded height and width, but still am not able to figure out how to get ahead of it.

Any help is highly appreciated!!

**EDIT:**
On w-20 and h-20, the images get circular and on doing w-25 and h-25 they become disproportionate again. Any lead on why so?

And on adding w-20 and-20 the text isn't in the middle anymore. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `tailwind`, you can use the CSS for `rounded-full` on the `image` tag. You need to provide a fixed height and width to the image as well like

```
<img class="w-50 h-50 rounded-full" src="pic.jpg" alt="Rounded avatar">
```

Here is Leonardo DiCaprio below for you :)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<img class="p-1 w-50 h-50 rounded-full ring-2 ring-gray-300 dark:ring-gray-500" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtyS3wBrnrkDXvhSo8SEXpvUXqXajtTSi9zD33IpKxAJHlijHnaY1pFT30NpaxxnP58PM&usqp=CAU" alt="Bordered avatar">
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the delay. Thanks a lot. it also worked

Answer (score 0):

Give your image's parent div element the same width and length and make it rounded full,
use this tailwind classes
`w-10 h-10 rounded-full`